# react-native flatlist needs to be scrolled for showing the updated content

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

[image]i am using flatlist to show user messages in a chat application and messages are being stored in react redux
now when the sender sends the messages it updates the store and flatlist gets updated
but on the sender side when message recieved through the socket same function runs that update the messages saved in stores but it wont update the flatlist.a user interaction is required to and the message appears for example when i scroll the flatlist the message get appended to the flatlist

i am not sure it is behaving differently on sender and reciever side

Answer (score 0):

**Use ScrollView component for Scrolling**

```js
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native'
```

Wrap your FlatList inside it

```js
<ScrollView>
<FlatList data={data} renderItem={MessageComponent} />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: didnt work... please check the .gif file i shared in the question